# How to think about wave-functions in experiments?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, interference

My basic understanding of quantum mechanics for random nature of it utilizes S-G experiment, in the sense that measurement depending on the state has some probability amplitudes for different measurements.

I am trying to extend this to more involved systems and in his book, Sakurai talks about gravity-induced quantum interference. I am not sure about how to use information about wave function to explain the details of the experiment, or at least not sure if the picture of it in my head agrees with the 'quantum mechanical way'.

I wanna ask,

1. The book says, the wave packet can be assumed smaller than the sizes of the loop, we can think of the paths as classical.
   I wonder, is here what does path mean that at any time when the wave propagates in the loop, packet is so localized around some points that practically any measurement of neutron would produce that it is at that localized point (since the wave function becomes very close to zero at other regions) with some standard deviation and this deviation is so small that we can think that neutrons are inside a segment of with $2\Delta x$ which practically is like a point.
2. How are wavefunction and de-Broglie wavelenght are related. Is this wavelenght , 'wavelenght' of the wavefunction in the sense that when waves meet most probable points of measruing neutrons are seperated by this wavelenght?

Comment: This question runs into the fact that whether the wavefunction means something at all is a interpretation dependent thing. There is a lot of arguing happening even right now.

Comment: i am okay with it. you can answer if those are correct deductions in Born's probability interpretation